I am installing vscode in ubuntu linux....but I am getting this some unmet dependencies error
ayushjain@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install --reinstall ./code_1.88.1-1712771838_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'code' instead of './code_1.88.1-1712771838_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 code : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.28) but 2.23-0ubuntu11.3 is to be installed
        Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.17) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
        Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.30) but 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.14 is to be installed
        Depends: libxkbfile1 (>= 1:1.1.0) but 1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


I tried installing the vscode using command sudo apt install /.code
but it is throwing 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 code : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.28) but 2.23-0ubuntu11.3 is to be installed
        Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.17) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
        Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.30) but 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.14 is to be installed
        Depends: libxkbfile1 (>= 1:1.1.0) but 1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

this error

update your question to tell folks what version of OS you are on  ... also on Ubuntu before doing above assure your box is current by issuing  sudo apt-get update &&  sudo apt-get upgrade ... also I do not know why you are not using current deb vscode version available from  https://code.visualstudio.com/download which is file code_1.89.0-1714530869_amd64.deb    also such Ubuntu non programming questions are better asked over on the sibling forum https://askubuntu.com/

There are many possible reasons for how you got to this point. Try the following, it won't make things worse, and might solve the problem you are having with apt:
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade -f

However, the recommended way to install VSCode on Ubuntu is to use Snap, which is not affected by the problems you are having with apt.
$ sudo snap install --classic code

See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_snap
